# Making the linear and quadratic terms independent in temporal data

Tags: regression, polynomial, centering, quadratic-form

I'm looking at the abundance of different groups of humans over time. These abundance data closely follow a quadratic model of the form

$y=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+ \varepsilon$

for all groups of humans, where $x$ is time and $y$ is abundance. For my research I'm paying close attention to both the linear and quadratic terms. I found that the $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ have a strong negative correlation. I know that this is expected, since these terms are not independent. I read that you can make $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ independent by centering $x$ around the mean before running the regression (Gelman, 2008). I can see how this works when $x$ and $y$ are different physical quantities (i.e. BMI vs. sugar consumption), but I don't know how to make $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ independent by centering $x$ (i.e. time) around the mean in a way that accounts for temporal autocorrelation (e.x. the number of humans over time).

How can I examine the relationship between the linear and quadratic terms (which are not independent) for temporal data.

- Gelman, A. (2008) Scaling regression inputs by dividing by two standard deviations.
  Statistics in Medicine, 27, 2865–2873.

Comment: *I can see how this works when $x$ and $y$ are different physical quantities (i.e. BMI vs. sugar consumption), but I don't know how to make $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ independent for temporal data (i.e. the number of humans over time).* This aspect of your question is unclear to me - surely $x$ and $y$ *are* "different physical quantities" if one is time and one is the population?

Comment: @Silverfish: That's correct. I think my phrasing was poor. Maybe a better way of saying this would be (since my problem is that the data is temporal) is "I don't know how to make $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ independent by centering $x$ around the mean in a way that accounts for temporal autocorrelation."

Comment: That makes more sense! I suggest you edit that into your question, so that people don't have to read through the comments to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you center a variable at the mean and then compute the square of that centered variable, then the centered variable and its square show no *linear* relation. There is still a strong non-linear relationship, but that is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It wasn't clear to me that the non-linear relationship is kept after centering. Does it make sense to center the variable if the variable is time? Something about that makes me think that it wouldn't be so simple for temporal data.

Comment: I see no problem with applying centering to time.